# Curved animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I want to move text in curve shape in relative layout in android.

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
                set.setFillAfter(true);
              Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
                rotation.setStartOffset(2000);
                rotation.setDuration(2000);
                TranslateAnimation moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 0);
                moveLefttoRight.setStartOffset(1000);
                moveLefttoRight.setDuration(1000);
                set.addAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
                set.addAnimation(rotation);
                txt_tilel2.startAnimation(set);
```

I tried this but in this text move left to right and then rotate.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the rotation animations's start offset to 2000 milliseconds, the translation animation's start offset to 1000 milliseconds and the translation animation's duration to 10000 milliseconds.

This means you actually

1. Start the animation set
2. after 1000 milliseconds your text begins moving
3. 1000 milliseconds after that it has finished moving and it begins rotating
4. 2000 milliseconds after that the rotation animation finishes

Instead you should set both animations' start offsets to the same value.